# Suppress gutters at sides in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on a website where I need to display a whole load of cards 2, 3 or 4 abreast in a div, depending on screen size. This is what I'm using for the row: `<div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-sm-3 row-cols-md-4">`. For the columns within, I have this: `<div class="col d-flex align-items-stretch">`. This all works fine, and I see the requisite numbers per row. But there is a gap to the left of the left-most card on each row, and to the right of the right-most. I only want gaps (gutters) within the row, not at the edges. How do I do this? (Or am I making things more difficult for myself than I need to and there is another easier way to do this?)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want gutters anywhere, you need the bootstrap class [`no-gutters`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

[image: bootstrap docs on no-gutters]

However in your case, you should be fine adding class `mx-0` to your `<div class="row">` element

Comment: Adding 'mx=0' has no visible effect, unfortunately. And it's not that I don't want any gutters, I want gutters between the cards within each row, just not at the sides.

Comment: ..... mx-0 .....

Comment: Sorry, that was what I meant.